# Getting error while creating Stripe Recipients on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, post

I'm using this code to create a Stripe Recipient:

```
let name = "John Doe"
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://api.stripe.com/v1/recipients")!)
let params = "\(stripeKey):&name=\(name)&type=individual&card=tok_15P1vqDxE2HbT5qyw3sI7tku"

    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = params.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) 
{ 
(url: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

    let string = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    println(string)
}
```

And getting this error:

```
"You did not provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in the Authorization header, using Bearer auth (e.g. 'Authorization: Bearer     YOUR_SECRET_KEY'). See https://stripe.com/docs/api#authentication for details, or we can help at https://support.stripe.com/."
```

What do I do?

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear to me. What do you not understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I talked to the Stripe staff and I was able to do it correctly. What I forgot on my code was on the header:

```
//Getting Recipient
let name = "John Doe"
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:"https://api.stripe.com/v1/recipients")!)
let stripeKey = "sk_test_XXX"
let params = "name=\(name)&type=individual&card=\(token.tokenId)"


request.setValue("Bearer \(stripeKey)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization") //This is what I had to add
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the [Stripe documentations](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios)? `StripePublishableKey` is the same as your API key.

```
// AppDelegate.m

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Stripe.h"

NSString * const StripePublishableKey = @"pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh";

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [Stripe setDefaultPublishableKey:StripePublishableKey];
  return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: Sorry for not saying, but I provided the key, but didn't want to post on StackOverflow for security reasons.

Comment: I see. I'm glad you found the answer.